# Missing most text on android emulator

Tags: android, text, flutter, dart, emulation

So I'm running the following code and no text is displayed on the emulator screen, the example app showed absolutely no text on screen. If I ran the app without a degugger attached, the text was there but disappeared when a refresh was made.

Same thing happens with API 24, 27, 28. On API 28 I didnt have any text in the home screen of the OS and sometimes half of the clock text was missing and half was there (like clock showed up as "  :22" instead of "10:22"), app titles text under their icons was missing.

Tried reinstalling devices and downloading new images. Same thing happens if running with xamarin.

Some images showcasing the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc2VA.jpg

Has anyone had to deal with this before?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the renderer in the emulator settings:

[image]

answer from https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/dc8n2a/missing_text_in_android_emulator/f29dk6z?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Yes, with
* OpenGL ES renderer: Desktop native OpenGL
* OpenGL ES API lever: Compatibility (OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0)